# installshield how to remove custom folder?

Tags: installshield

My programm creates folder **LOGS**
How to delete this folder while uninstall?
I should use the removeFile table, but I can't understand, how to set folder **LOGS**. May be I should set it on Components?

I saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4wEs5JQHnU) tutorial, but there is installed folder, not new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can remove only that folder which exists in **Directory** table.
To accomplish it:
 - Create this LOGS folder in InstallShield IDE (or directly in Directory table)
 - Create custom component for this folder, for example C_Logs_folder
 - Use these things in **RemoveFile** table:
`FileKey | Component_    | FileName | DirProperty | InstallMode`
`--------------------------------------------------------------`
`LOGS    | C_Logs_folder |          |   LOGS      |           2`
*DirProperty* should be the same as in **Directory** table