# How to remove a custom non empty folder - using Installshield?

Tags: installshield

Is it possible to remove a custom non empty directory which has subfolders when the application is uninstalled?
Using RemoveFile table, deletion of directory doesn't work.
Please suggest a way to delete a custom directory on uninstallation of windows application.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the RemoveFile table should work with any folder. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283615/installshield-how-to-remove-custom-folder/25376966#25376966) QA for details. 
Also you can use Custom Actions to remove folder, here is you can use:

- EXE file having a path referencing a directory ([Custom Action Type 34](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368092(v=vs.85).aspx)). For example: CMD.EXE /C "DEL /S /Q c:\needed_folder" from System folder
- InstallScript
- VBScript

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx             Referring to this ,RemoveFile works only if the directory is empty. But i have sub folders inside a folder and i want to remove all the sub folders on uninstalling.

Comment: Create two entries in RemoveFile: one for Folder, second one for all files and subdirs. For second one set * instead of empty Filename column

Comment: Thanks. It worked for files only. Sub directories could not deleted.