# How to remove default INSTALLDIR in installshield

Tags: installshield

I have a Basic MSi project in installshield 2012 that allows the user to change the installation path, the default installation path is a fixed path C:\xxx directory. The problem is that if the user decides to install the application in another location that the default C:\xxx folder the system will do that, but it will also create and empty C:\xxx folder!
How can I prevent this?

with regards,
Ehsan

Comment: Do you sure that INSTALLDIR (which you set on General view) exactly C:\xxx? If so, you might try to remove this folder from CreateFolder table with help of DirectEditor.

Comment: I want to remove it if the user has chosen a new directory to install the software, so now I'm looking into using a script or some custom action.

Comment: RemoveFile table will help you. It's better than using CA (custom action) you can refer to this QA (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283615/installshield-how-to-remove-custom-folder/25376966#25376966) for details or search in internet.

Comment: Hello Igor, I tried the method it does work but I don't think this is the correct way for my problem. I need to check if the INSTALLDIR has changed and if so then call the RemoveFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the components panel you need to go through all the components and on each one change the "Destination" field from C:\xxx to [INSTALLDIR]xxx.

The is problem that a component, possibly a registry component or SQL component, has a "Destination" of C:\xxx and even though no files are copied as part of the component InstallShield still creates the folder.

Comment: Thanks, as you said there was two components that had static paths.